# How to store many to many relationship in Laravel without pivot model?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a many to many relationship I have 2 main table and 1 pivot table

`user`

```
id : 1
name : lily
```

`event`

```
id: 1
event_name: Waterpark Waterday
-------
id: 2
event_name :Theme Park Adventure
```

`event_user`

```
id : 1
event_id : 2
user_id : 1
-------------
id :2
event_id :1
user_id :1
```

Both table user and event is create already. Pivot table or relationship only created when user wants to join the event. So when user clicked on apply button it will only store the `event_id` and `user_id` I wanted to create things like that. But I have problem and I don't quite sure on how to save it. It did try but I keep getting error.

Comment: in controller $event = Event::find($request->event_id);

Comment: did you pass `$event->id` on  `register.blade.php` ?

Comment: oh I'm getting something there but I have error with `BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\User::event()`

Comment: @lily then the relation name ( event() ) is wrong, kindly update with model code relations or full xD will be easier for us to help you

Comment: @AlzafanChristian I have updated the model

Comment: $user->event()->attach($event); -> it should be $user->events()->attach($event);

Comment: there you go, should be $user->events() rather than $user->event(); you can use Dilip approach code. ill  just give an optional answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `attach` and `detach` method.

You may also use the `sync` method to construct many-to-many associations. The `sync` method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table:

```
$user->events()->sync([1,2]);
```

In array `1,2` is event id.

You can read more in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

**Note**

for `sync, attach` you should define relationship in model.

**User** Model

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event','event_user','user_id','event_id');
    }
}
```

**Event** Model

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','event_user','event_id','user_id');
    }
}
```

As based on your code.

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$user->events()->sync([$request->event_id]);
```

Comment: Does this code means that I have to manually store the id inside the code? `sync([1,2]);`  I prefer no hardcoded code since it is a system that will be use later

Comment: Please check to Note I have edited. you need to make relationship in model. after you can use sync and attach too,

Comment: sir I have question  is sync method replace the old id? Because I tried to add multiple event_id with the same user id, and i realized that the old event id got deleted. and only store the newest one.

Comment: attach and detach is for hasone or hasmany, with many to many always use sync. many advantages of using it.

Comment: thank you for explaining it. I decided to use this method but modify it with `syncWithoutDetaching()` as Alzafan has mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

my optional answer:

(since attach is more faster than sync when you have a big data)

```
//get current synced id
$attachedIds = $user->events()->pluck('id');
//check if there is a new id selected
//if its a single id
$new_id = array_diff([$request->event_id], $attachedIds);
//if its already an array
$new_id = array_diff($request->input('event_id', []), $attachedIds);

$user->events()->attach($new_id);
```

Comment: I will definitely try both method to understand better and compared. Thank you :)

Comment: @lily forgot to mention that laravel has alternative method like my answer syncWithoutDetaching() just take a look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships or use sync($array_id, false)

Comment: Oh i just realized that this sync method remove the old ID?  when the same user register a new event

Comment: @lily yes, so i put an optional answer, and you can read my previous comment :)

Comment: yes I did. Thank you sir :) works better and understand much better now. Thank you